# Calculating employee pay with methods

Tags: java, methods

I am having trouble with a part of an assignment where i have a method to calculate the regular pay of an employee but if the hours worked is over 40 then the rest is overtime but in if the user types in 50 hours with a 10 dollar rate it will print out 500 but i want it to to only print out 40 of those 50 hours and take the rest as overtime.

```
package paytime;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    String firstName, lastName, choice;
    double hoursWorked, hourlyWage, weeklyPay;
    Employee one = new Employee();

    System.out.print("Enter Y to process employee or any other key to end: ");
    choice = scn.nextLine();
    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    {

    System.out.print("Enter employee number: ");
    int number = scn.nextInt();

    while (!one.findEmpNumber(number))
    {
        System.out.print("Invlaid, enter a proper employee number: ");
        number = scn.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    firstName = scn.next();

    System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
    lastName = scn.next();

    System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
    hoursWorked = scn.nextDouble();

    while (hoursWorked < 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Negative hours not allowed. Enter hours worked: ");
        hoursWorked = scn.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $");
    hourlyWage = scn.nextDouble();

    while (hourlyWage < 0 || hourlyWage > 100)
    {
        System.out.print("Negative wage is not allowed or wage entered is to high. Enter hourley wage: $");
        hourlyWage = scn.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.println(" ");

    if (hoursWorked <= 40.0)
    {
    System.out.println("Worker " + number + " Paycheck Information: ");
    System.out.println("Name is: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    System.out.println("Weekly Pay is: " + one.callWeeklyPay(hoursWorked = 40, hourlyWage));
    System.out.println("Income Taxes is: " + one.callIncomeTax());
    System.out.println("Net Pay is: " + one.callNetPay());
    }
    else if (hoursWorked > 40.0)
    {
    System.out.println("Worker " + number + " Paycheck Information: ");
    System.out.println("Name is: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    System.out.println("Weekly Pay is: " + one.callWeeklyPay(hoursWorked, hourlyWage));
    System.out.println("Income Taxes is: " + one.callIncomeTax());
    System.out.println("Net Pay is: " + one.callNetPay());

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("Worker " + number + " Overtime Calculation");
    System.out.println("Name is: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    System.out.println("Weekly Pay is: " + one.callOvertimePay());
    }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Total number of Employees processed: ");
    }
}
}


package paytime;

public class Employee {

private int empNumbers [] = {101, 103, 106, 109, 110, 113, 116, 118, 120};
public double weeklyPay, hoursWorked, hourlyWage, incomeTax, netPay, actualOvertimeHours, overtimePay, overtimeHours;
public double overtimeWage = hourlyWage * 1.5;

public boolean findEmpNumber(int number)
{
    boolean found = false;
    for (int sub = 0; sub < empNumbers.length; sub++)
    {
        if (number == empNumbers[sub])
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
private void calculateWeeklyPay(double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage) {

    weeklyPay = hoursWorked * hourlyWage;
}

public double callWeeklyPay(double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage) {

    calculateWeeklyPay(hoursWorked, hourlyWage);
    return weeklyPay;
}

private void calculateIncomeTax() {

    if (weeklyPay > 0.0 && weeklyPay <= 300.0)
    {
        incomeTax = weeklyPay * 0.10;
    }
    else if (weeklyPay > 300.1 && weeklyPay <= 400.0)
    {
        incomeTax = weeklyPay * 0.12;
    }
    else if (weeklyPay > 400.1 && weeklyPay <= 500.0)
    {
        incomeTax = weeklyPay * 0.15;
    }
    else if (weeklyPay > 500.1)
    {
        incomeTax = weeklyPay * 0.20;
    }
}

public double callIncomeTax() {

    calculateIncomeTax();
    return incomeTax;
}

private void calculateNetPay() {

    netPay = weeklyPay - incomeTax;
}

public double callNetPay() {

    calculateNetPay();
    return netPay;
}

private void calculateOvertimePay() {

    overtimeHours = hoursWorked -40;
    overtimePay = ovetimeHours * overtimeWage;
}

public double callOvertimePay() {

    calculateOvertimePay();
    return overtimePay;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: yes i will post it

Comment: when i run the code everything works up till one.callovertimepay() method it does not display anything

Answer (score 0):

When you call `callWeeklyPay` method subtract 40 from the `hoursWorked`.

```
one.callWeeklyPay(hoursWorked - 40, hourlyWage));
```

But I would suggest moving the logic of checking for overtimes(hours exceeding 40) inside the `Employee` class (`callWeeklyPay` method) itself.